# Python3 : can I lock multiple locks simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, locking

I have multiple locks that lock different parts of my API.

To lock any method I do something like this :

```
import threading

class DoSomething:
    def __init__():
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        with self.lock:
            # do stuff requiring lock here
```

And for most use cases this works just fine.

But, I am unsure if what I am doing when requiring multiple locks works or not :

```
import threading

class DoSomething:
    def __init__():
        self.lock_database = threading.Lock()
        self.lock_logger = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        with self.lock_database and self.lock_logger:
            # do stuff requiring lock here
```

As it is, the code runs just fine but I am unsure if it runs as I want it to.

My question is : are the locks being obtained simultaneously or is the first one acquired and only then the second is also acquired.

Is my previous code as follows ?

```
with self.lock1:
    with self.lock2:
        # do stuff here
```

As it is, the code currently works but, since the chances of my threads requiring the same lock simultaneously is extremely low to begin with, I may end up with a massive headache to debug later

I am asking the question as I am very uncertain on how to test my code to ensure that it is working as intended and am equally interested in having the answer and knowing how I can test it to ensure that it works ( and not end up with the end users testing it for me )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but beware of [*deadlocks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). A deadlock occurs when one thread is unable to make progress because it needs to acquire a lock that some other thread is holding, but the second thread is unable to make progress because it wants the lock that the first thread already is holding.

Your code example locks `lock_database` first, and `lock_logger` second. If you can *guarantee* that any thread that locks them both will always lock them *in that same order,* then you're safe.  A deadlock can never happen that way.  But if one thread locks `lock_database` before trying to lock `lock_logger`, and some other thread tries to grab them both in the opposite order, that's a deadlock waiting to happen.

Looks easy. And it is, *except...*

...In a more sophisticated program, where locks are attached to objects that are passed around to different functions, then it may not be so easy because one thread may call some `foobar(a, b)` function, while another thread calls the same `foobar()` on the same two objects, except the objects are switched.

Comment: I was aware of deadlocks, I was more afraid of a client having an issue and me trying to understand what was going on through emails or - worse - the phone x)

Comment: I wish I could delete this answer. IDK why the OP accepted it. It looks to me as if I completely misunderstood what they were asking.

Comment: hum no, it did answer the question correctly. I was in a context where I needed to know if I had the right approach in order to get multiple locks at once. As far as I am aware there are no `with lockA and with lockB :` so you need to get locks one by one and then run into the possible issue of deadlocks. Unless I am unaware of a feature or have misunderstood the answer ( possible ) it did indeed answer the question